# AbstractNioSelector Unexpected exception in the selector loop

Tags: memory-leaks, playframework, websocket, netty

I'm running WebSocket server with Scala Play Framework 2.4.6 and Netty 3.10.6.Final on production. Oracle JDK 8.

Usually, the server works fine, but on high load, it fires exceptions and starts leaking Linux socks.

```
2017-05-16 15:18:28,149 WARN  o.j.n.c.s.n.AbstractNioSelector Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.isEventsHighKilled(EPollArrayWrapper.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.setUpdateEvents(EPollArrayWrapper.java:190) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.add(EPollArrayWrapper.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.implRegister(EPollSelectorImpl.java:178) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.register(SelectorImpl.java:132) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker$RegisterTask.run(NioWorker.java:151) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

The problem happens when 1800 users connect to the server. Then memory and Linux sockets grow. It's really hard to debug this and I didn't google any sockets leak issue in Play Framework release notes.

I saw the similar question in SO, but I don't control server sockets manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Java bug. Please open an issue on the openjdk issue tracker and include the stacktrace..

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK, but same happened on Open JDK as well. Does they share same issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

1. I filled issue, and Oracle responded that such exception is likely already fixed in JDK9 (in JDK-8168500).
2. We was able to fix that by reducing number of threads for akka.

Answer (score 0):

This may be JDK-8168500, fixed in JDK 9. Can you say what the kernel version is here? When this issue originally came up then it could only be reproduced by dynamically changing file descriptor limit.

Comment: uname -a:

Linux api1 4.4.0-1013-aws #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 15:41:31 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: And, yes we granted increased file descriptor limit after start of application. Is that could be a cause?